# JQuery DataTable rowCallback is called on change of checkbox in IE 11

Tags: jquery, datatables

By the refrence of the following snippet `JQuery` `DataTable` `rowCallback` is called when I change the checkbox. This checkbox is in the header of a table and once it will be checked all of the checkboxes in the table will be checked or unchecked depending on the status of parent check box.

This is working fine in `chrome` and `rowCallback` does not fire even when I change the state of check box. Once I chnage the state of check box in `IE 11`, `rowCallback` will be fired and will render all of the check boxes again and this will remove the current state of all other check boxes.

**Following is the snippet**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tableID").on('change', "#cbCheckAll", function(e) {

        //Once it is fired it will fire rowCallback also and if it was checked it will render all checkboxed again beacuse rowCallback was fired. This is happening only in IE 11 and working fine in Chrome.
        var table = $('#tableID').DataTable();
        var cells = table.rows({
            search: 'applied'
        }).nodes();
        var listChkBox = $(cells).find(".foo:enabled");
        var cbCheckAll = this.checked;
        $(listChkBox).each(function() {
            //This fires correctly on both Chrome and IE 11 but rowCallback is also fired.
            this.checked = cbCheckAll;
        });
    });
});

$("#tableID").DataTable({
    bAutoWidth: false,
    data: JsonData,
    destroy: true,
    paging: false,
    order: [],
    info: false,
    columns: [

        {
            data: null,
            title: "<input id='cbCheckAll' type='checkbox' />",
            defaultContent: "",
            className: "chkBox"
        }

    ],

    rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {

        //Fired even the cbCheckAll change is fired.
        var chkBx = "<input class=\"foo\" type=\"checkbox\">";
        $(row).find(".chkBox").html(chkBx);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderable:` `false` and `searchable`: `false` fixed this issue like following:

```
{
    data: null,
    title: "<input id='cbCheckAll' type='checkbox' />",
    defaultContent: "",
    className: "chkBox", 
    orderable: false, 
    searchable: false
}
```